# Ubuntu 18.04 dropbox-client items cluttering up Status Notifier list

Tags: notification, dropbox

Each time I reboot, another "dropbox-client-PID" gets added to the Known Items list in the Status Notifier Items menu (right click on the Status Notifier in the panel and select properties). I can move the old dropbox-client items down to the bottom of the list, but cannot find out how to remove them. And over time they may build up to a point that they impact the system (e.g. does Status Notifier traverse this list in its operations? Is this a malloced linked list or a fixed size array? etc).

Is this a Status Notifier bug? Or a Dropbox bug? Or can I somehow clean up this list?

Comment: This happens also in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior, but I don't know who's bug it is. Anyhow, left below the Known Items list there is a button "Clear Know Items" where you can get rid of them

Comment: What does it mean that an item is known?

Comment: Sorry. I don't recall and I don't have the 18.04 Version. In 20.04 I don't see this happen. Anyhow I am in the change to 22.04 now, so for the time being this doesn't bother me any longer.

Comment: Well, I have the issue in 20.04.